# How to assign a single value to a new column corresponding to multiple values in other columns?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm creating a dashboard for customer tracking. My data is coming from a SQL database, where each row corresponds to a customer, and there's a "date" column that contains the date of the interaction. I want to display a matrix on the dashboard showing the number of customers served by date (this has already been done), but I also want to assign 20 slots for appointments each day.

I've tried various approaches, including merging tables, but since there can be multiple occurrences of a date (multiple customers on the same day), the number of slots isn't correctly quantified. I need to ensure that there are ONLY 20 slots available each day. What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Starting with a [Date table](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2013/11/19/generating-a-date-dimension-table-in-power-query/) in Power Query create a table that has one row per slot per day like this:

```
let
    DatesWithRange = Table.AddColumn(Date,"SlotNumber",each {1..20}),
    #"Expanded Slots" = Table.ExpandListColumn(DatesWithRange, "SlotNumber")
in
    #"Expanded Slots"
```

Or you can do something similar in your database.